# jQuery multiple class .hover issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm still a bit of a jQuery noob. I'm creating a fitness website where a user can hover over different body parts which then highlight a different colour. I want all divs with class 'arms' to turn red when a user hovers ONE of the arms (ids "leftarm" and "rightarm") but at the moment, nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated :)

HTML

```
<div id="muscleStructure">
  <div class="arms" id="leftarm">
  </div>
  <div class="arms" id="rightarm">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#muscleStructure{
  position:relative;
  width:150px;
}
.arms{
  height:150px;
  width:25px;
  background:#CF6;
  position:absolute;
  top:15px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#rightarm{
  right:0px;
}
#leftarm{
  left:0px;
}
```

Javascript

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">

$(".arms").hover(function(){
   $(".arms").css("background","#F00");
   },function(){
   $(".arms").css("background","#CF6");
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this otherwise all the elements with class arms backgroung color will get changed:

```
$(".arms").hover(function(){
   $(this).css("background","#F00");
   },function(){
   $(this).css("background","#CF6");
});
```

also wrap it in `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//your code here

});
```

**UPDATED:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">  </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".arms").hover(function(){
   $(this).css("background","#F00");
   },function(){
   $(this).css("background","#CF6");
});

});

</script>
```

Change the code like this:

[**WORKING FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/W6XxX/)

Comment: I WANT all class 'arms' to change! But at the moment, even when changed to this code, it does nothing at all.

Comment: Yes I have, but it's not doing anything even though it works on the fiddle.

Comment: No, just HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Comment: whenever you include a jquery script or library it should be like this

Comment: and for writing your code use a separate script tag other wise behavior will be unexpected

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".arms").hover(function(){
   $(this).css("background","#F00"); // $(this) instead $('.arms')
   },function(){
   $(this).css("background","#CF6"); // $(this) instead $('.arms')
});
```

You're applying css to all elements in the DOM which are having class `.arms`, Target the current element which is hovered and you will see the desired effect.

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6a4b/)

Comment: I'd like both arms to change when I hover over one or the other though.